# VB.net add a header/footer to every page of a PDF using iText7

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext7

I am trying to create a PDF with a header and footer. Both header and foot are images. Since my pdf creates a random amount of pages I need to automaticly add it to every page. I know I need to use some sort of eventhandler. Unfortunately I can't find any examples in the vb.net language, I only can find java/C# examples and I am really bad at reading/converting these language to vb.net. I am not a expert yet at programming.

Can anyone point me in the right direction.

Edit4: Removed random stuff no longer need to answer my question.

This piece of code below is all I got on creating the PDF itself.

```
Imports System.IO

Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Imports iText.Kernel

Imports iText.Kernel.Pdf

Imports iText.Kernel.Font

Imports iText.Kernel.Font.PdfFont

Imports iText.Kernel.Font.PdfFontFactory

Imports iText.IO.Image

Imports iText.IO.Image.ImageData

Imports iText.IO.Image.ImageDataFactory

Imports iText.Layout.Element.Image

Imports iText.Layout

Imports iText.Layout.Element

Imports iText.Layout.Element.Table


Imports iText.Kernel.Events.Event

Imports iText.Kernel.Events.PdfDocumentEvent

Imports iText.Kernel.Geom.PageSize

Imports iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle

Imports iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument


Imports iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfNumber

Imports iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter

Imports iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.PdfCanvas

Imports iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.PdfCanvasConstants

Imports iText.Kernel.Pdf.Xobject.PdfFormXObject

Imports iText.Layout.Canvas

Imports iText.Layout.Document

Imports iText.Layout.Style

Imports iText.Layout.Layout.LayoutArea

Imports iText.Layout.Layout.LayoutContext

Imports iText.Layout.Layout.LayoutResult

Imports iText.Layout.Renderer.CellRenderer
Imports iText.Layout.Renderer.DrawContext
Imports iText.Layout.Renderer.TableRenderer
Imports iText.Signatures.PdfSignatureAppearance


Public Sub NewiText7PdfCreation()

'Dim dest As String = "\\test\verkoop\offerte v2\Offerte " & offertenummer2 & "-" & offertenummer & " " & TextBox2.Text & ".pdf"

Dim dest As String = "iText7Test.pdf"


Dim writer As PdfWriter = New PdfWriter(dest)
Dim pdf As PdfDocument = New PdfDocument(writer)
Dim doc As Document = New Document(pdf)

Dim font As PdfFont = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont("C:\Windows\Fonts\calibri.ttf")

'header

Dim headerlocation As String = "Resources\Offerte-NL.png"
Dim headerimage2 As Image = New Image(ImageDataFactory.Create(headerlocation))
doc.Add(headerimage2)


'klant gegevens

doc.Add(New Paragraph("Debiteur gegevens").SetFont(font))

Dim debnr As String = TextBox1.Text
Dim bn As String = TextBox2.Text
Dim adr As String = TextBox3.Text
Dim pcwp As String = TextBox4.Text
Dim cp As String = TextBox5.Text
Dim km As String = TextBox6.Text

Dim klanttable As New Table(2)

klanttable.SetMaxWidth(350)
klanttable.SetHorizontalAlignment(0)
klanttable.SetFont(font)
klanttable.SetFontSize(8)
klanttable.SetWidth(350)
klanttable.SetMinWidth(120)

klanttable.AddCell("Debiteur nr.: ")
klanttable.AddCell(debnr)
klanttable.AddCell("(Bedrijfs)naam:")
klanttable.AddCell(bn)
klanttable.AddCell("Adres:")
klanttable.AddCell(adr)
klanttable.AddCell("Postcode & woonplaats:")
klanttable.AddCell(pcwp)
klanttable.AddCell("Contactpersoon:")
klanttable.AddCell(cp)
klanttable.AddCell("Kenmerk:")
klanttable.AddCell(km)

Dim cell As New Cell

klanttable.SetMarginTop(10)
klanttable.SetMarginBottom(10)

doc.Add(klanttable)

doc.Close()

End Sub
```

Edit:

Found a nice tutorial on the iText website.

https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-net/chapter-3-using-renderers-and-event-handlers

I just don't quite get how to insert that piece of code into my own piece of code. I think I need to create a new class that handles the event.
But how do I need to call this event.

I just add the follow line to my code:

```
Implements IEventHandler
```

And this new sub.

```
  Public Sub HandleEvent([event] As [Event]) Implements IEventHandler.HandleEvent
    Throw New NotImplementedException()
End Sub
```

How do I adjust the sub to handle the page-start event and page-end event ( if it's even still called that way)

Edit: I just imported all the stuff just to be sure I got everything. When everything is working fine I am just gonna remove everything not being used.

Comment: So what you are saying is, you found C# examples, and you want someone to translate them to VB.NET for you? Similar to what you asked in your question about iText 5: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47769659/how-do-i-add-a-footer-in-a-pdf-using-itextsharp-vb-net

Comment: Can you access Google at your place? Try searching for "c# to vb.net" and you will get: http://converter.telerik.com/ and http://www.carlosag.net/tools/codetranslator/ Should be sufficient.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse No I don't want someone to translate everything for me. I just I want to know how to call the pageend and pagestart events/handlers. In iText5 I got this stuff working at the moment. But iText7 is so different and I am failing to find the way to do it.

Comment: @Sunil I tried those converters but I am getting weird results which I can't seem to get working, I think it has trouble converting the iText parts.

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse I edited my question, I hope you can see what I am messing up.

Comment: *"This is the piece of code I found in C# and translated it to vb.net"* - it looks like the piece of code you found was in Java, not C#...

Comment: @mkl You are completely right found the code here http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext7/samples/blob/develop/samples/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/samples/sandbox/events/TextFooter.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some efforts, I could implement PAGE_END event in vb.net. Here is the code for you.

(A) In main module create pdf routine add:

```
*Dim HandlerRLA = New VariableHeaderEventHandlerRLA
PDFfile.AddEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, HandlerRLA)*
```

(B) Add anlother class after End Class. You may add text/paragraph as per requirement. I have used image as Header and Footer on specific pages.

```
Public Class VariableHeaderEventHandlerRLA
    Implements IEventHandler
    Dim header As String
    Dim doc As PdfDocument
    Public Sub TextFooterEventHandler(ByRef doc As PdfDocument)
        Me.doc = doc
    End Sub
    Public Sub HandleEvent([event2] As [Event]) Implements IEventHandler.HandleEvent
        Dim docEvent1 As PdfDocumentEvent = event2
        Dim canvas1 As PdfCanvas = New PdfCanvas(docEvent1.GetPage())
        Dim pageSize1 As iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle = docEvent1.GetPage().GetPageSize()
        'Dim canvas As Canvas = New Canvas(docEvent.GetPage(), New iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle(0, 0, pageSize.GetWidth(), pageSize.GetHeight))
        Dim PDoc1 As PdfDocument = docEvent1.GetDocument()
        Dim Page1 = docEvent1.GetPage()
        Dim PageNo1 As Integer = PDoc1.GetPageNumber(Page1)

        If PageNo1 > 1 Then
            Dim imageFile, BottomImage As String
            imageFile = "path to image folder\secondtop.bmp"
            Dim data3 = ImageDataFactory.Create(imageFile)

            BottomImage = "path to image folder\secondbottom2.bmp"
            Dim data4 = ImageDataFactory.Create(BottomImage)

            Dim Ratio = data3.GetHeight / data3.GetWidth
            Dim rect As iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle = New iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle(0, 784, 595, 595 * Ratio)

            With canvas1
                .AddImage(data3, 0, 784, 595, 0)
                '.AddImageFittedIntoRectangle(data3, rect, 0)

                Ratio = data4.GetHeight / data4.GetWidth
                rect = New iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle(0, 0, 595, 595 * Ratio)
                '.AddImageFittedIntoRectangle(data4, rect, 0)
                .AddImage(data4, 0, 0, 595, 0)
            End With
        End If
        'Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You need to import some .net controls.